# Why EventBus need ThreadLocal for the EventWithHandler

Tags: events, event-handling, guava

im getting confused that why eventbus need threadlocal here?

```
  /** queues of events for the current thread to dispatch */
  private final ThreadLocal<Queue<EventWithHandler>> eventsToDispatch =
      new ThreadLocal<Queue<EventWithHandler>>() {
    @Override protected Queue<EventWithHandler> initialValue() {
      return new LinkedList<EventWithHandler>();
    }
  };
```

**JUST FOR** AsycEventBus to override the method enqueueEvent and dispatchQueuedEvents ??

Comment: What alternative did you have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's used to handle reentrant posting of events--for example, if one event subscriber posts one or more other events, they'll go in to the queue. Then those events can be posted to their subscribers *after* the event bus finishes handling the current event.